# Extjs 5 - Filefield submit error

Tags: extjs, file-upload, cross-domain

I have a filefield and a spring controller to receive the images from the form submit. My spring controller is working, i see the request and the success response but my form callback give me this error.

```
responseText: "{success:false,message:"Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame."}"
```

In the browser request, i see the correct response but i dont see this response. What is can do to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you post some code so that it would be clear how you send the request and url you run the app from and url where you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using spring and this configuration fixed the same issue for me.

```
<security:headers>
   <security:frame-options policy = "SAMEORIGIN"/>
</security:headers>
```